# Spring JPA Criteria API

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA Criteria API to fetch all records which is saved before 3 months.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("criteria")
    public List<CorporationAudit> find(){

        Specification<CorporationAudit> specifications = Specification
                .where(AuditSpecification.find());

        return corporationAuditRepository.findAll(specifications);
    }
```

**AuditSpecification**

```
public static Specification<CorporationAudit> find(){
        return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(3);
            return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updateAt"),date);
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

by using above specification, I'm getting all records for all corporation which is saved before 3 months, but I want to fetch records for any specific Corporation, so how I can add this criteria?

Comment: Just add it... `where(spec1).and(spec2)`...

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah exactly I'm looking for how to add where condition but exactly I don't know how & where to add "where(spec1).and(spec2)", pls help

Comment: In your code after the where... It isn't more magical than that.

Comment: @M.Deinum if I add another specification so how it will compare for the corporation as my Specification is return only date comparison?

Comment: Again just add it... The query will do both now. \